# Polymer 1.0 Paper Radio Group Conditions

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I can't get a function to trigger when a button is selected in Polymer 1.0. Essentially when, for example, "medium" is selected, an alert should pop up. I am very new to Polymer and trying to get my head around it.

```
<dom-module id="my-app">
    <template>
      <paper-radio-group selected="{{selection}}">
        <paper-radio-button name="small" label="Small"></paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="medium" label="Medium">Meduim</paper-radio-button>
        <paper-radio-button name="large" label="Large"></paper-radio-button>
      </paper-radio-group>
    </template>
    <script>
      Polymer({
        is: "my-app",
        ready: function () {
          if (this.selection === "medium") {
            alert("medium");
          }
        }

      });
    </script>
  </dom-module>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, you'll need to wire your bindings up to notify you when selection changes. First, set up the `selection` property, then define an observer to it. The observer callback will be called whenever the property value changes.

```
...
Polymer({
  is: "my-app",
  properties: {
    selection: {
      type: String,
      observer: "selectionChanged"
    }
  },
  selectionChanged: function (newval, oldval) {
    if (newval === "medium") {
      alert("medium");
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Is there any documentation for events like these to read up on? I am very new and would like to read how you knew the answer. Thanks. BTW, your answer works like a charm!

Comment: No worries - unfortunately I haven't come across any other better source for Polymer documentation other than what's already there in the Polymer website (https://www.polymer-project.org). You can check this (http://chuckh.github.io/road-to-polymer/) out for some additional info, but I feel the best way to learn is to actually look at the codes for elements published in https://github.com/PolymerElements. It's a good way to learn the patterns commonly used.

Comment: I'll have a go on those documents. Thanks again